# Send PHP's JSON response from an API call as part of AJAX success function

Tags: php, ajax, api

I have setup a page that takes the data from a form, serializes into JSON and then uses AJAX to call a PHP file to process the form data and send it to an API via cURL.

How can I get the response from the API to come back as part of the AJAX's success function?

At the start of my project, I was able to accomplish this because I was using the php as an include. But cannot use that method because the file is being executed from the AJAX call not from an include.

I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://jonsuh.com/blog/jquery-ajax-call-to-php-script-with-json-return/), but just kept catching errors.

I've also scoured, reviewed and attempted more suggestions from various posts on this site than I can even count. Now, I'm asking for some help.

Here is the pertinent ajax on my **index.php** file.

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    dataType : 'json',
    async: false,
    url: 'save_application.php',
    data: { filename: fileName,  applicationData: jsonFormString, job: adid },
    success: function () { console.log("done");},
    failure: function() {console.log('error');}
});
```

And here is the relevant part of the **save_application.php** file.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  //stuff here
));

$applicantresponse = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

And lastly, the **$applicantresponse** that comes back is formatted like this:

```
{
  "applicationId": 123456789,
  "links": {
    "link1": "https://thisisalinkforLINK1.html", //THIS IS THE VALUE I WANT
    "link2": "https://thisisalink.html",
    "link3": "https://thisisalink.html"
  }
}
```

Ultimately, I want to set a variable to the value for links->resume (ex: `var resumeLink = (something goes here); \\returns https://thisisalinkforLINK1.html)` back on my index.php within the success function so I can use that response for some other to-dos.

Comment: You need to output a response to the jQuery code, which isn't happening here. Does your PHP output anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to output `$applicantresponse` from your `save_application.php` file so that it's returned to your calling code, and you need to change the `success` function in your ajax code to then use that data.  It'll look something like this:

```
$applicantresponse = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

echo json_encode($applicantresponse);
```

and then...

```
$.ajax
({
    ...
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.links.link1);
        // do something with the data that was returned
    },
    ...
});
```

One thing that is important is that your php code not output *any* other text to the client.  All other `echo`, `print`, debugging calls, all of that stuff, has to be removed, because otherwise you're not sending back valid json encoded data that jQuery knows how to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `save_application.php` uses the data submitted by `$.ajax` for the curl request, and you need to send part of the curl response back to the client to be used in the success function.

The curl response is already JSON, so the simplest thing to do is just

```
echo $applicantresponse;
```

which will send the entire curl response back to the client.

If you only want to send one of the links of it, you'll need to decode it and extract the specific piece you want, then re-encode that piece.

```
$applicantresponse = json_decode($applicantresponse);
$link = $applicantresponse->links->link1;
echo json_encode($link);
```